# Blender Subsurface Scattering on Certain Area

Tags: light

Is there a way to increase the `Subsurf Scattering`just for certain areas like Vertex Groups?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Vertex Colors:

[image: vertex colors]

Go to `Object Data` in the Properties panel and add a new slot for Vertex Colors. You can then go to `Vertex Paint` mode and paint wherever you want the subsurface to be.

Unlike Vertex Groups, Vertex Colors can be brought into materials with the Vertex Color node. (`Shift+A > Vertex Colors > YourVertexColors`).

Comment: Great tip, thanks!